# Can't start 2010 workflow after migration from Sharepoint 2010 to 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow

I recently upgrade my Sharepoint foundation 2010 to Sharepoint 2013. It was successful.
But after this, I am not able to start my old workflows. In addition, if i create a new list and a new 2010 workflow, I am not able to start them as well.
The button to "start workflow" just does not do anything.
Afterwards the error that gets logged into the workflow history is userid->system account and

> Failed to start(retrying)

what might be the cause?

Comment: Have you start workflow using system account?

Comment: Yes. I tried it using System Account. It failed. Then I again tried it using a different account , it again failed.

Comment: any event log details that you can share ? also did you verify the options to support backward compatability of event handlers at web app level settings